# Bootstrap .nav-pills folding alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nav-pills as a collection of toggles for a tagging system. It is an unordered list with list elements. The list items are setup like this with Jade and NodeJS:

```
.row
  .tagnav.col-xs-12
     ul.ptag.nav.nav-pills
        each tc in tagColours
           li(onClick="selectTag('"+tc.tag+"', '"+tc.colour+"')").active #{tc.tag}
```

The row is aligned in the centre of the screen with:

```
.tagnav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

like so:

[image]

As I make the window more narrow the nav-pills start to fold (which is good) but the layout is not pleasant. This is what they look like when I make the window smaller:

[image]

I would like them to line up nicely in centred rows. Like this (photoshopped):

[image]

I am using Jade for my HTML so I can get the tags dynamically from an array on the server so for the jsfiddle I've just put the tags in statically. They seem to behave the same. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLa2e94o/)

Thanks.

Comment: One thing, keep in mind that flex-direction: row is default, so unless you're overriding something it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this makes it better:

```
.ptag.nav-pills > li.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.nav-pills>li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bnn9f3a3/**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the flex style..

*(see fiddle below for a more readable comments explanation)*

```css
.tagnav {
    display: flex;
 }
 
 .ptag {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1;
 }
 
  li {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex: 1;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   text-align: center;
   font-variant: small-caps;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
.ptag.nav-pills > li.inactive {
  color: #909090;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tagnav col-xs-12">
      <ul class="ptag nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">tech</li>
        <li class="active">art</li>
        <li class="active">electronics</li>
        <li class="active">dsp</li>
        <li class="active">c++</li>
        <li class="active">openframeworks</li>
        <li class="active">processing</li>
        <li class="active">graphics</li>
        <li class="active">java</li>
        <li class="active">unity3d</li>
        <li class="active">c#</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

based on your html structure

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/x3mu0k1d/

original, for others

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/h8w58rzd/

Comment: This looks nice, but you are changing the HTML structure... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ahh yea, I didn't look at the fiddle. But yours is better, centered, non-stretched look is best in my opinion ;)

Comment: Thanks dude... `:)` Yours is awesome too, but this is not the right one for this instance. `:)`